# How to construct "lowercase digits" (i.e. text figures)?

Tags: typography, text, resize, line-height

Is there an accepted way to adjust font glyphs in order to simulate [**text figures**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_figures)?

[image]

### Background

Text figures are "lowercase" digits. You normally use lowercase digits where you also use lowercase text (e.g. in the middle of a sentence).

Keyboards were never created with uppercase and lowercase digits; and Unicode doesn't specifically encode them, as *"they are not considered separate characters from lining figures, only a different way of writing the same characters."*

Which brings me to my question; what is the accepted way to create lowercase figures out of a font's standard "uppercase ones?

Wikipedia mentions that *normally*:

- `012` are `x`-height
- `68` have ascenders
- `34579` have descenders

[image]

My first attempt (in photoshop) would be to:

- smush **012**
- nudge **34579** down
- leave **68** where they are:

[image]

[image]

But the ***skwooshed*** figures (0, 1, 2) look distinctly unpleasant.

If the Unicode consortium suggests that "lowercase digits" can simply be constructed from te "uppercase" ones - what do they recommend i do?

### Ideally in HTML

My end goal is to display lowercase text in a browser. i know some fonts (e.g. Georgia) already display **all** their digits as lowercase:

[image]

But i'm not asking how to switch to using **Georgia**; i'm asking how to *construct* lining figures out of non-lining ones.

And since this is for display on the web, i realize that i'd probably end up having to apply per-character formatting:

```
<!doctype html">
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            font-family: "Segoe UI", "Calibri", sans-serif;
            font-size: larger;
        }

        .xheight {
            font-size: 1.5ex;
        }

        .descender {
            position: relative;
            bottom: -0.4ex;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p>In the year <span class="xheight">21</span><span class="descender">5</span><span>6</span> the Romulan war...
</body>
</html>
```

Rendering as:

[image]

Which, again, doesn't look as pleasing as i think it should.

### Hey look, a penny!

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The very short answer is "No."

Oldstyle figures ("lowercase") are specifically drawn that way. Legacy Postscript and TrueType fonts, for the most part, contain only tabular figures, which are lining or oldstyle according to the way the font is designed.

The Unicode Consortium isn't suggesting that lining figures can be distorted into oldstyle figures, simply that there is only one set of Unicode values for the digits 0-9, regardless of whether there are multiple glyphs for each digit.

Many OpenType fonts contain both lining and oldstyle figures, in both tabular and proportional widths, with tabular lining figures being the usual default. These are all available to applications which are OpenType-aware, typically through a preference setting in a character or paragraph style. They share Unicode values, but they are separately drawn alternate glyphs that exist (or don't) as outlines in the font software. (Of the font families in your CSS, Calibri has oldstyle figures, but Segoe UI does not.)

From a typographic point of view, not only is there no accepted way to do what you ask, I'd say there is no *acceptable* way, either. As you've discovered, trying to get there by shifting baselines and distorting lining figures looks horrible.

Comment: Good answer, but it seems to beg the question when browsers will be fully OpenType-aware, to the extent of being able to specify in CSS which style of numbers to use when a font contains both.

Comment: It is also an important point out that there is no way to guarantee that "Segoe UI", "Calibri", nor even sans-serif is the actual font displayed. The exact baseline and x height values used may look even more awful in Arbitrary Olde Style which the user has installed.

Comment: Any insight on why the Unicode Consortium didn't encode separate glyphs for uppercase and lowercase digits, but **did** encode separate glyphs for uppercase `A` (`U+0041`), lowercase `a` (`U+0061`), and even sᴍᴀʟʟ cᴀᴘɪᴛᴀʟ `ᴀ` (`U+1D00`)? I.e. what might be the reasoning that excludes separate uppercase and lowercase digits, but includes separate uppercase and lowercase letters?

Comment: And finally, can you name an OpenType font that contains both *"uppercase"* and *"lowercase"* digits?

Comment: @e100 There's nothing I've seen in the WC3 documentation that indicates that's being considered. The WC3 people don't go to the same Starbucks as I do, so I don't have an inside track on things. :)

Comment: @IanBoyd It was an unfortunate decision, imo, but it is what it is. As for fonts with both, Calibri is one that ships with MS Office so is commonly available. Linotype's Palatino has both. The Adobe fonts Garamond Pro, Jenson Pro, Caslon Pro, Minion Pro and Myriad Pro all have both. There are many, many fonts on the market that incorporate oldstyle and lining figures. Most font foundries and font sites show the OpenType features available in a particular font, so you can easily check.

Comment: i only ask about fonts because (as of this moment) the only way i know how to inspect characters of a font is `Charmap`, which only shows Unicode characters. i know **charmap** doesn't support investigating other font features, such as ligatures. Obviously i have to to do some hunting for a *"font viewer"*. But knowing Calibri supports them gives me a benchmark for any viewers i find.

Comment: @IanBoyd: Regular uppercase and lowercase characters are distinct in meaning and thus switching between them is much more than a stylistic choice. Uppercase and lowercase numbers are identical in meaning, however, and thus simply are nothing that Unicode wants to encode – for the same reason that there are no specific encodings for italics, small caps, lowercase and similar. The small-caps characters you find are only encoded because they have a distinct meaning in phonetics and should not be used for emphasis (for this, you should use OpenType features or similar).

Comment: @IanBoyd: By the way: Characters that are only accessible by OpenType features and similar are often also encoded in the Private Use Area of Unicode as a fallback solution, so you get a good estimate of what characters a font has by looking there. But please note that they are really only a fallback solution and should only be used when you really need those characters and cannot use OpenType features or similar. This is because they are not searchable and are likely to be replaced by nonsense, if the font is replaced for some reason.

Answer (score 6):

The correct way to render lowercase digits/numbers or "Oldstyle figures" is to use CSS to select a suitable font feature. Obviously, the used font should then support this font feature in the first place. Real world support with webfonts does not seem to be too strong.

The CSS setting you are looking for is

```
font-feature-settings: "onum";
```

and the documentation:

- [MDN: font-feature-settings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/font-feature-settings)

Documentation of OpenType features, and `onum` feature in particular, can be found in [Microsoft's OpenType Layout tag registry](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/otspec/features_ko.htm#onum).

Alternative documentation about font features is available in the article [How to code OpenType features in CSS](http://blog.webink.com/opentype-features-css/).

Officially, you're supposed to use

```
font-variant-numeric: oldstyle-nums;
```

but support for that seems to be even weaker according to [Mozilla's Browser Compatibility reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-variant-numeric).

In theory this is better because it doesn't refer directly to OpenType features so it should work with non-OpenType fonts, too. In the same way you should use:

```
font-variant: small-caps;
```

to enable *small caps*. Do **not** use OpenType feature setting such as

```
font-feature-settings: "smcp";
```

to achieve this effect because `font-variant` property is already well supported.

Comment: No, you never want to use `font-variant: small-caps;` because that create **FAKE** small caps. Always use the other one, and always use OpenType fonts. Simple and solved.

Comment: According to definition (https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/fonts.html#propdef-font-variant) it's `acceptable` if `small-caps` feature is faked. That is not a requirement and high quality user agent would do the right thing (map it to OpenType feature). I agree that if you rather have no change instead of faked small caps, you should use `font-feature-settings`. Usually fake small caps is better than having no effect at all.

Comment: @tchrist: ...the difference being?  If it's capital, and it's small, it's a small cap.  Problem solved.

Comment: Faked small caps does the "small" part by scaling the actual upper case letters smaller to match the normal lower case x-letter height. Of course, this also makes the letters visually thinner because the whole letter is scaled down which makes the stemlines narrower, too. Proper small caps support has separate set of letters which are optically heavier to match the weight of the upper case letters. A well made small caps set may also have slightly different shapes for the small caps letter to match the overall font better.